# Vulkan depth image binding error

Tags: vulkan

Hi I am trying to bind depth memory buffer but I get an error saying as below. I have no idea why this error is popping up.

The depth format is VK_FORMAT_D16_UNORM and the usage is VK_IMAGE_USAGE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT.  I have read online that the TILING shouldnt be linear but then I get a different error. Thanks!!!

The code for creating and binding the image is as below.

```
VkImageCreateInfo imageInfo = {};

// If the depth format is undefined, use fallback as 16-byte value
if (Depth.format == VK_FORMAT_UNDEFINED) {
    Depth.format = VK_FORMAT_D16_UNORM;
}

const VkFormat depthFormat = Depth.format;

VkFormatProperties props;
vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties(*deviceObj->gpu, depthFormat, &props);

if (props.linearTilingFeatures & VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT) {
    imageInfo.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR;
}
else if (props.optimalTilingFeatures & VK_FORMAT_FEATURE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT) {
    imageInfo.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Unsupported Depth Format, try other Depth formats.\n";
    exit(-1);
}

imageInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
imageInfo.pNext = NULL;
imageInfo.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
imageInfo.format = depthFormat;
imageInfo.extent.width = width;
imageInfo.extent.height = height;
imageInfo.extent.depth = 1;
imageInfo.mipLevels = 1;
imageInfo.arrayLayers = 1;
imageInfo.samples = NUM_SAMPLES;
imageInfo.queueFamilyIndexCount = 0;
imageInfo.pQueueFamilyIndices = NULL;
imageInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
imageInfo.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_BIT;
imageInfo.flags = 0;

// User create image info and create the image objects
result = vkCreateImage(deviceObj->device, &imageInfo, NULL, &Depth.image);
assert(result == VK_SUCCESS);

// Get the image memory requirements
VkMemoryRequirements memRqrmnt;
vkGetImageMemoryRequirements(deviceObj->device, Depth.image, &memRqrmnt);

VkMemoryAllocateInfo memAlloc = {};
memAlloc.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO;
memAlloc.pNext = NULL;
memAlloc.allocationSize = 0;
memAlloc.memoryTypeIndex = 0;
memAlloc.allocationSize = memRqrmnt.size;

// Determine the type of memory required with the help of memory properties
pass = deviceObj->memoryTypeFromProperties(memRqrmnt.memoryTypeBits, 0, /* No requirements */ &memAlloc.memoryTypeIndex);
assert(pass);

// Allocate the memory for image objects
result = vkAllocateMemory(deviceObj->device, &memAlloc, NULL, &Depth.mem);
assert(result == VK_SUCCESS);

// Bind the allocated memeory
result = vkBindImageMemory(deviceObj->device, Depth.image, Depth.mem, 0);
assert(result == VK_SUCCESS);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, linear tiling **may not** be supported for depth usage Images.
Consult the specification and Valid Usage section of [VkImageCreateInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkImageCreateInfo). The capability is queried by [vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#vkGetPhysicalDeviceFormatProperties) and [vkGetPhysicalDeviceImageFormatProperties](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#vkGetPhysicalDeviceImageFormatProperties) commands. Though depth formats are "[opaque](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#features-formats-depth-stencil)", so there is not much reason to use linear tiling.

This you seem to be doing in your code.
But the error informs you that you are trying to use a memory type that is not allowed for the given Image. Use [vkGetImageMemoryRequirements](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#vkGetImageMemoryRequirements) command to query which memory types are allowed.

Possibly you have some error there (you are using 0x1 which is obviously not part of 0x84 per the message). You may want to reuse the example code in the [Device Memory chapter of the specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VkPhysicalDeviceMemoryProperties). Provide your `memoryTypeFromProperties` implementation for more specific answer.

Comment: HI thanks for the help... for memoryTypeFromProperties I get memRqrmntTypeBits as 132. and 132 is VK_FORMAT_BC1_RGB_SRGB_BLOCK = 132. I get unsupported depth format, try othe depth format.

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally set the typeIndex  to 1 instead of i and it works now. In my defense I have been vulkan coding the whole day and my eyes are bleeding :). Thanks for the help.

```
bool VulkanDevice::memoryTypeFromProperties(uint32_t typeBits, VkFlags      
requirementsMask, uint32_t *typeIndex)
{
    // Search memtypes to find first index with those properties
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    if ((typeBits & 1) == 1) {
        // Type is available, does it match user properties?
        if ((memoryProperties.memoryTypes[i].propertyFlags & requirementsMask) == requirementsMask) {
            *typeIndex = i;// was set to 1 :(
            return true;
        }
    }
    typeBits >>= 1;
}
// No memory types matched, return failure
return false;
}
```